# Reset Keychain in swift and IOS 10 crash

Tags: swift, keychain, ios10, swift2

The problem happen on only in Xcode 8 and IOS 10.
If I use XCode 8 and IOS 9 it is working perfectly.

```
func resetKeychain() {

    if !self.keychainItemData.isEmpty {
        let tempDict = self.dictToSecItemData(self.keychainItemData)
        var junk = noErr
        junk = SecItemDelete(tempDict as CFDictionary)

        assert(junk == noErr || junk == errSecItemNotFound, "Failed to delete current dict")
    }

    self.keychainItemData[kSecAttrAccount] = ""
    self.keychainItemData[kSecAttrLabel] = ""
    self.keychainItemData[kSecAttrDescription] = ""

    self.keychainItemData[kSecValueData] = ""
}
```

The assert is always happening in IOS 10 and the app crash

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Xcode Project, go to the app target and then to Capabilities. Turn on Keychain Sharing. That should do the trick!

Comment: I didn't even thought about it as it was enabled before the update to XCode 8

Comment: Life saver! Worked for me!